# How do I get the UID in user-profile.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to make a custom view mode for user profiles. In my `user-profile--myviewmode.tpl.php`, I want to get the UID for the user whose profile it is.

The help text for `user-profile.tpl.php` states:

> $user_profile: An array of profile items. Use render() to print them.
>   Field variables: for each field instance attached to the user a
>   corresponding variable is defined; e.g., $account->field_example has a
>   variable $field_example defined. When needing to access a field's raw
>   values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these
>   variables. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired
>   field language, e.g. $account->field_example['en'], thus overriding
>   any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.

I used `dpm()` to print out the array `$user_profile`, but I couldn't find the UID anywhere.

Then I tried:

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
```

However, this doesn't work because when I use Views to render the view mode, it gives me the UID of the logged-in user, not the user whose profile is being rendered.

Is there a way to get the UID in `user-profile.tpl.php`?  I need to get the UID to build some custom links based on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the uid under the elements >> #account object:

```
$elements['#account']->uid;
```

Good luck!